# Google Analytics transform report data

Tags: google-analytics

I want to build a custom report on the past year's (historical) data in Google Analytics that has a custom column that's a transformation of data from another column.

That is, I want to strip out the querystring and /##### at the end of the URI to make another column so that all pages are grouped properly. I don't want to filter the raw data that's coming into GA, just the data on the report.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in Analytics reports.
You can export the data in a Spreadsheet (or Excel) and clean it, or in the reports you can filter all the desired rows (eg with a regex) and read the total values ​​of the metrics in the total row (under the header of the tabele).